# I'm getting this error again & again whenever I run "yum list updates"

Tags: yum

```
# yum list updates
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management.
You can use subscription-manager to register.
```

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

Comment: You start by checking which repositories are configured.

Comment: Another thing that you'll notice is that the system isn't registered so it doesn't have access to the Red Hat repos. If this is by design and you only want to get packages from other repos, then you'll need to make sure that they are enabled. Add the output of `yum repolist` to your question.

Comment: You need to use `subscription-manager` to add your RHEL license key to the server. You can get a license for free from red hat if this is a non-production server through their developer program.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting this error again & again whenever I run this command. Anyone knows the solution?

*yeah, stop running that command  :)*

---

all the repository definitions are in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`

and you have an **empty** `redhat.repo` file because you installed rhel however you did (which is fine) but you never *activated* your installation with a given rhel license... which is not necessarily bad it just means you don't have access to the official redhat repositories to properly update your system and install any other software or libraries that redhat may provide.

For example my redhat.repo file looks like this...

```
#
# Certificate-Based Repositories
# Managed by (rhsm) subscription-manager
#
# *** This file is auto-generated.  Changes made here will be over-written. ***
# *** Use "subscription-manager repo-override --help" if you wish to make changes. ***
#
# If this file is empty and this system is subscribed consider
# a "yum repolist" to refresh available repos
#

[rhel-7-server-extras-rpms]
metadata_expire = 86400
enabled_metadata = 1
sslclientcert = /etc/pki/entitlement/16959377048969.pem
baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/extras/os
proxy =
ui_repoid_vars = basearch
sslverify = 1
name = Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Extras (RPMs)
sslclientkey = /etc/pki/entitlement/169048969744555-key.pem
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
enabled = 1
sslcacert = /etc/rhsm/ca/redhat-uep.pem
gpgcheck = 1

[rhel-7-server-rpms]
metadata_expire = 86400
enabled_metadata = 1
sslclientcert = /etc/pki/entitlement/1695934543375315.pem
baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/$releasever/$basearch/os
proxy =
ui_repoid_vars = releasever basearch
sslverify = 1
name = Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server (RPMs)
sslclientkey = /etc/pki/entitlement/1695935504896975315-key.pem
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
enabled = 1
sslcacert = /etc/rhsm/ca/redhat-uep.pem
gpgcheck = 1
```

it has much more, with a lot of `enabled=0` but what is populated will depend on the rhel license you purchased.  But those two I show above are basically the main ones you really need for basic functionality.

You can also get `epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm` from
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

or if you have a network connection now you can simply do right now

`yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`

or for rhel8: `yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm`

after which you will see an `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`.  And EPEL is free so you can do that right now and access whatever EPEL has to offer.  But EPEL does not offer kernel updates, you need to pay whatever the basic rhel subscription cost is these days to register your system with the redhat repo.

Also know there are many other repositories you can point to, most are free some are paid for.  And CentOS is RHEL, where CentOS is free with no official [paid for] support.

https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

*if you using linux for personal/home/fun then definitely use CentOS, you're not missing anything by not using RHEL.  If it's a system at work and there's legalities and what not then your company should be paying for a rhel subscription.  But know that many people do use CentOS officially in a work environment just fine just be aware there is no paid-for official support with centos like there is with rhel.*

Comment: Bt my redhat.repo  is like this.                                                                                                                                     ]# cat redhat.repo
#
# Certificate-Based Repositories
# Managed by (rhsm) subscription-manager
#
# *** This file is auto-generated.  Changes made here will be over-written. ***
# *** Use "subscription-manager repo-override --help" if you wish to make changes. ***
#
# If this file is empty and this system is subscribed consider 
# a "yum repolist" to refresh available repos